# Intellij Idea 14 + HIbernate query

Tags: java, hibernate, intellij-idea

Whenever I write hibernate query such as this:
`session.createQuery("from Table")`
IntellijIdea 14 marks the word "from" as an error and show this description for it: "'from' unexpected". Although project compiles successfully (maven) and everything works fine in production.

So my question is: **How to prevent IDE from fail-marking that kind of code?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable an inspection for highlighted issue in the editor

1. Set the caret at the word `from`
2. Click the bulb icon or press Alt+Enter to reveal the inspection alert and suggestion list.
3. **Hover** to the inspection to be disabled, then **click** right arrow button or just press the right arrow key.
4. On the submenu, click Disable "inspection name"

[image]

Refer to [IntelliJ Doc](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/disabling-and-enabling-inspections.html) for another ways

Answer (score 2):

JetBrains / IntelliJ provides coding assistance, such as syntax highlighting, in string literals via "Language Injection".

You can set the language to inject via `Settings > Editor > Language Injections`.

In your case, you need to set the language for `org.hibernate.Session` to Hibernate QL / HQL. I had to do the same thing for `javax.persistance.EntityManager`.

[image]