# IntelliJ IDEA doesn't understand Hibernate Query Language (HQL)

Tags: intellij-idea, hql

When I work with HQL in IntelliJ IDEA, it always highlights my Hibernate queries:

[image]

I know how I can *disable* that highlighting, that is already [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39948392/intellij-idea-14-hibernate-query).

But is there support of HQL in IntelliJ IDEA? Is there any way to use something like *query auto-completion*?

Maybe an option in settings or some plugin.

Comment: You're using JPA. I suggest you use standard, correct JPQL, and thus always specify the select clause: `select p from Product p`.

Comment: @JBNizet thank you for remark. It's actually the same IDEA behavior with JPQL. Now I corrected my question.

Comment: In your project structure, click on"Facets", then add JPA, choose your provider, and click the + icon to specify the persistence.xml.

Answer (score 6):

JetBrains / IntelliJ provides coding assistance, such as syntax highlighting, in string literals via [Language Injection](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-language-injections.html).

You can set the language to be injected via `Settings > Editor > Language Injections`.

In your case, you need to set the language for `org.hibernate.Session` to Hibernate QL / HQL. I had to do the same thing for `javax.persistance.EntityManager`.

[image]

Comment: This fixed the syntax issue and I also had to add a JPA facet under project structure so the Table names were correctly resolved.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what for me resolve the same issue: Open in the IDEA Preferences (Settings)/Editor/Language Injections and under the list of languages find Session (org.hibernate). Under the column Language, it should be selected Hibernate QL. Double click on it and a list of operations will be displayed. Select the operations that you need.
[image: IDEA Settings]